# Disable a Checkstyle rule from a Gradle `build.gradle` file

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

It is possible to run the Checkstyle linter from Gradle, without having to write a configuration `.xml` file.  Here is an example:

```
/// Checkstyle linter
// Run by `gradle check`, which is run by `gradle build`
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
ext.checkstyleVersion = '10.5.0'
configurations {
  checkstyleConfig
}
dependencies {
  checkstyleConfig("com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:${checkstyleVersion}") { transitive = false }
}
checkstyle {
  toolVersion "${checkstyleVersion}"
  ignoreFailures = false
  config = resources.text.fromArchiveEntry(configurations.checkstyleConfig, 'google_checks.xml')
}
```

However, I do not see how to disable/suppress a particular check, still from the `build.gradle` file.

I want to disable the LineLength check.  None of these works:

```
checkstyle {
  ...
  configProperties += ['LineLength.max': 140]
  configProperties += ['LineLength.enabled': false]
  configProperties += ['suppressions.suppress': 'LineLength']
}
```

What is the right invocation, if there is one?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to disable the rule in the build.gradle file? Why not add a `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` file to your project?

Comment: I have dozens of projects that enable checkstyle in their `build.gradle` file, and I do not wish to create a `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` file in each of those projects, then try to keep them all in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Your apparent intention is start with a stock Checkstyle configuration and customize it for your projects. Let's write a Gradle script to transform the Checkstyle configuration. The script deletes the LineLength module.

```java
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

def readCheckstyleConfig() {
  def xslt = '''
      <xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output
            doctype-public="-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
            doctype-system="https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="module[@name='LineLength']">
          <!-- Delete this module. -->
        </xsl:template>
      </xsl:transform>
      '''
  def transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
      .newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)))
  def xml = resources.text.fromArchiveEntry(
      configurations.checkstyleConfig, 'google_checks.xml').asReader()
  def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
  transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xml), new StreamResult(stringWriter))
  return resources.text.fromString(stringWriter.toString())
}

checkstyle {
  toolVersion = checkstyleVersion
  config = readCheckstyleConfig()
}
```

The above code merely demonstrates the idea. In practice, you would not copy the code into many build.gradle files, then try to keep the copies in sync. Gradle recommends [convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_publishing_convention_plugins.html) to share build logic across multiple projects.